# Angular Material Datepicker with ControlValueAccessor and formControlName

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

I am trying to utilize ControlValueAccessor with Angular Material datepicker. For some reason, its not not working with formControlName and a reactive form. Can someone resolve this? The wrappers are being built for certain styling and attributes. The values are sent to reactive form, etc

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

**Typescript:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-picker',
  templateUrl: './date-picker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-picker.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatePickerComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ], host: {
    '(change)': 'onChange($event)',
    '(blur)': 'onTouch()'
  }
})

export class DatePickerComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() Value: Date = new Date();
  @Input() PlaceHolder: string;
  @Input() Label:string;
  @Output() dateValueAction = new EventEmitter();

  onChange: any = () => { };
  onTouch: any = () => { };
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  set valueUpdated(val) {
    this.Value = val;
    this.onChange(val);
    this.onTouch(val);
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    this.Value = obj;
    this.valueUpdated = obj;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }

  dateValueChanged() {
    this.valueUpdated = this.Value;
    this.dateValueAction.emit(this.Value);
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>{{Label}}</mat-label>   
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder={{PlaceHolder}} [(value)]="Value" (dateChange)="dateValueChanged()">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
        <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon>calendar_today</mat-icon>
    </mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Wanting to implement with formControlName, etc

```
<app-date-picker formControlName="startDate">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When implementing `ControlValueAccessor` you shouldn't use the standard input/output communication mechanism. 
The input value is provided by `writeValue`, notification of changes to the control (output value) is done by calling the callback function provided by `registerOnChange`.

Please try the following code:

```js
export class DatePickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  private value: Date = new Date();
  @Input() placeHolder: string;
  @Input() label: string;

  private onChange: Function;
  private onTouch: Function;

  writeValue(obj: Date): void {
    this.value = obj;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: Function): void {
  this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: Function): void {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }
  dateValueChanged(): void {
    this.onChange(this.value)
  }
}
```

Also, you specified a class directly in the descriptor for the component decorator. doing so you shouldn't be using `forwardRef`.

```js
 providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: DatePickerComponent,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
```

Comment: thanks, this is the older syntax also with Angular Material https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885568/custom-component-mddatepicker-used-in-reactive-form feel free to post your answer there if needed